# How does this need JSON to be resolved at all?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, joomla

I run into a little problem that needs your help. I am coding in a Joomla module, but this is not really a problem to all those who are not Joomla-friendly.

In a Joomla's module, there will be a folder named `tmpl` (`template` for short I think) that contains a little file `default.php`, which is where the view will be presented to the browser. Here is roughly a part of the file I am dealing with

```
!DOCTYPE HTML
<?php 
// perform some initialization
?>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var obj=["o1","o2","o3","o4",...,"o_n"];
    //do something with range obj
});

</script>

<div>
    <div class="content">
        <?php
            if(is_set($array))
            {
                foreach($array as $key=>$val):
            ?>
                //GET $val->id
            <?php
                //display $val->$content
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the `foreach` loop I would like to get all the integral ids inside `$val` which will be fed back into the above javascript's `obj` variable as strings. I would need this to be done automatically; when the page loaded, the `obj` in javascript is initialized and when I added a new `$val` item into the database, this must too be done automatically (I don't have to open this default page to edit the `obj`).

Do you understand the problem I am having right now, please ask and reply. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to build the array you want to pass to JS in PHP, then `json_encode` it and pass it as is to JS. It would be easier than to build it in JS, then afterwards extend it via generated JS code. See this for example:

```
!DOCTYPE HTML
<?php 
// perform some initialization
?>

<?php
$obj = array("o1","o2","o3","o4",...,"o_n");
if(is_set($array)) {
    foreach($array as $key=>$val) {
        $obj[] = $val->id;
    }
}
?>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var obj=<?php echo json_encode($obj); ?>;
    //do something with range obj
});

</script>
```

Another way would be to use AJAX calls to fill this array, but that's not always the best approach, so I'll leave it up to you to decide.

Comment: Thank you Jadkik, that looks very promising. I'll try out what you suggest, the jason method first and re-do it with ajax too if i have some time.

Answer (score 0):

When rendering the page makeup the javascript as string and output that. So when your page is loaded (AFTER you already build the array object) it will excecute it as JS.

Hope this helps